# Unity NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, unity3d

Сразу. Я все ссылки на объекты уже поставил, 3 раза перепроверил, так что проблема не в этом.

Код (сокращённый):

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using TMPro;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

public InputField LoginLogin;
public InputField PasswordiLogin;

public GameObject notify;
public TextMeshProUGUI notifyText;

MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection("server=127.0.0.1;user=root;database=user;password=pfhfpf0207;port=20111;");
MySqlCommand command;

public void Login()
    {
        connection.Open();
        command = new MySqlCommand("SELECT password FROM user WHERE login = '" + LoginLogin.text + "'", connection);
        if (command.ExecuteScalar().ToString() == PasswordiLogin.text)
        {
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("logged", 1);
            PlayerPrefs.SetString("username", LoginLogin.text);
            notify.SetActive(true);
            notifyText.text = "Success login!";
        } else
        {
            notify.SetActive(true);
            notifyText.text = "Error logging in! Check your password or just wait.";
        }
        connection.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Не по вопросу но, никто не коннектица к `sql` через клиент. Проект декампилируется и злоумышленник видит адреc, логин и пароль. Запросы кидаются через простенький `php` скрипт, который работает с бд. А на тему вопроса, нет в этом и ты не указал строчку кода на которую указывает ошибка.

Comment: Проблема, очевидно, в "этом". Компилятору вас не за чем обманывать.

Comment: @Yaroslav IL2CPP сложно декомпилировать, но возможно конечно. Строка с ошибкой if (command.ExecuteScalar().ToString() == PasswordiLogin.text). Сейчас разберусь с PHP скриптом.

Comment: @StopperGames да хоть IL2CPP, по поиску `sql`, найти труда не составит, от слова "совсем".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Просто создал PHP скрипт.

```
<?php
$mysqli = mysqli_connect("host", "login", "password", "database");
$res = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT password FROM user.user WHERE login = '" . $_GET["login"] . "'");
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
foreach($row as $response) {
    if ($response == $_GET["password"]) {
        echo "true";
    } else {
        echo "false";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Каким образом это отвечает на поставленный вопрос?

Comment: @RiotBr3aker я просто использовал другой способ, замена моей старой системы и есть решение

Comment: Стоит об этом упомянуть, ведь ваш вопрос может помочь кому-то в будущем.